# Decrease Date( Month ) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-format

I want to minus three months from `2014-11-05 23:18:07.452957-07`. It should give output like `2014-08-05 23:18:07.452957-07`
I am trying this:

```
 SELECT created_on, DATE (created_on - INTERVAL '5 months') FROM user_authentication_logs   
 WHERE user_id = 1014 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1
```

But date format is changed. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*But date format is changed*" is not an acceptable error/problem description. What is the output you get? Note that dates and timestamp columns do **not** have "a format". Any "format" you see is applied by the SQL client _displaying_ that value.

Comment: I am getting this 6/5/2014. I want to keep date format as it is.

Comment: Then your SQL *client* displays the dates like that. Either change the configuration of your SQL client or use the `to_char()` function to format the date the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

For first, just remove the `Date` casting by replacing the:

```
SELECT created_on, DATE (created_on - INTERVAL '5 months') FROM user_authentication_logs   
 WHERE user_id = 1014 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1
```

by

```
SELECT created_on, created_on - INTERVAL '5 months' as created_on_minus_5_months FROM user_authentication_logs   
 WHERE user_id = 1014 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1
```

Because [Date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) type contains only date (no times)

And if your date format output is changed you can customize it using the [t_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) fucntion

Answer (score 0):

Try This out
I think This is you want

```
 SELECT created_on, cast((created_on - INTERVAL '5 months')as timestamp with time zone) FROM user_authentication_logs   
 WHERE user_id = 1014 ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1;
```